# How to update cell data without previous value clearing in NodeJS(google-sheets-api)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I working on NodeJS, Google Sheets API
I try to add some logs to a cell on a sheet, the logs are created each time that my code has executed a function (creating logs). Each time code updates the cell, my previous logs are erased. How I can get rid of overwrite in a cell? I want that my new logs are kept with old

I tried to change `sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({})` to
`sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({})`, but can't find related parameter there

```js
async regressionMapBatchUpdateSheet(auth, cellsRange = "", ...restValues) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
                spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
                requestBody: {
                    data: [
                        {
                            range: cellsRange,
                            values: [
                                restValues
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
                    includeValuesInResponse: true
                }
            }, (err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(`The sheet were updated, cells were updated: "${response.data.responses.map(res => res.updatedData.values)}"`);
                    resolve(response);
                }
            })
        });
```

values: [restValues] = my entered logs

I want to keep my logs in a cell. There would be great if logs will be started from new line each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to append a value to new row using Sheets API with Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

### Modification point:

- I think that using the method of values.append is suitable for your situation.

### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetid',
    requestBody: {
            data: [
                {
                    range: dateCell,
                    values: [
                        [date]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    range: resultCell,
                    values: [
                        [result]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    range: commentCell,
                    values: [
                        [comment]
                    ]
                }
            ],
            valueInputOption: "RAW",
            includeValuesInResponse: true
        }
}, (err, response) => {
```

#### To:

When you use this, please set the range and values. By this script, the values are append to new row.

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(
  {
    spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetid',
    range: "Sheet1!A:A", // This is a sample range.
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    resource: { values: [["date", "result", "comment"]] } // This is a sample value.
  }, (err, response) => {
```

### Note:

- From your question, I could confirm that you have already been able to use Sheets API.
- In this case, the value can be set like `{ values: [["date", "result", "comment"]] }`.

### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

## Edit:

- You want to add the value to the same cells without overwriting. For example, the cells `A1:B1` have `sample1` and `sample2`. When the values of `sample3` and `sample4` are added to `A1` and `B1`, respectively, the cells become `sample1sample3` and `sample2sample4`.

From your reply comment, I could understand like this. For this situation, unfortunately, in the current stage, this cannot be directly achieved by one API call. So it is required to do the following flow.

1. Get values from `A1:B1`.
2. Put values to `A1:B1` by updating the values.

In order to do this, for example, how about using the method of `spreadsheets.values.get` and `spreadsheets.values.update`?

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetid',
    requestBody: {
            data: [
                {
                    range: dateCell,
                    values: [
                        [date]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    range: resultCell,
                    values: [
                        [result]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    range: commentCell,
                    values: [
                        [comment]
                    ]
                }
            ],
            valueInputOption: "RAW",
            includeValuesInResponse: true
        }
}, (err, response) => {
```

#### To:

In this case, the cells of `Sheet1!A1:B1` are updated by adding the additional values to the existing values. For example, when the cells `Sheet1!A1:B1` have `sample1` and `sample2`, by running this script, the cells are updated to `sample1sample3` and `sample2sample4`.

```
const spreadsheetId = "###";
const range = "Sheet1!A1:B1";
const additionalValue = [["sample3", "sample4"]];
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
  {
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: range
  },
  (err1, result1) => {
    if (err1) {
      console.log(err1.errors);
      return;
    }
    const newValue = result1.data.values.map((row, i) =>
      row.map((col, j) => col + additionalValue[i][j])
    );
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
      {
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: range,
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
        resource: { values: newValue }
      },
      (err2, result2) => {
        if (err2) {
          console.log(err2.errors);
          return;
        }
        console.log(result2.data);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it slightly different from what I want.
'values.append' method adds a new row. My way is adding a data to exactly the same cell what was used earlier. For clear understanding let me show an example,
I added values to cells with range Sheet1!A1:B1, if I will add values to the range again, I want to see them without overwrite the previous values.  If it possible could you provide for another way to resolve my issue. Thanks again

Comment: @Vasiliy Pivovarov Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. You want to add the value to the same cells without overwriting. For example, the cells ``A1:B1`` have ``sample1`` and ``sample2``. When the values of ``sample3`` and ``sample4`` are added to ``A1`` and ``B1``, respectively, the cells become ``sample1sample3`` and ``sample2sample4``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yeah you are definitely correct, that is what I want

Comment: @Vasiliy Pivovarov Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your situation. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Vasiliy Pivovarov Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I had vacation. It works as I expected! Thank you so much! Sure I set that the answer solved my issue

Comment: @Vasiliy Pivovarov Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.